# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/trueaccord/scalapb/GeneratedEnum

Tags: java, playframework

I just start to learn play, and download the example here https://www.playframework.com/download

Play Java Starter Example(Play 2.6.x Starter Projects)

when I run the commond “sbt run” in the terminal, I come across the following error

```
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/trueaccord/scalapb/GeneratedEnum
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
[error]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
```

My error image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried every possible ways for about two hours, the final resolution is change the sbt version in the /project/build.properties

change

```
sbt.version=1.1.2
```

to

```
sbt.version=1.1.4
```

Hope that can give you some help.